# Django Rest Framework, кастомный @action не создает нужного эндпоинта

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Помогите понять, почему не существует эндпоинта `api/users/register`, но существуют `api/users/{pk}/register`?

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .serializers import UserSerializer

class UserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    @action(methods=['POST'], detail=True)
    def register(self, request):
        serialized = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serialized.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=serialized.data['username'],
                password=serialized.data['password'],
                email=serialized.data['email']
            )
            user.save()
            return Response('user registered', status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response('invalid data', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'id')
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers

from api import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserView, 'users')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действие декарированое `@action` в зависимости от значения аргумента `detail`  может быть предназначено как для отдельного объекта, так и для всей коллекции. В вашем случае необходимо использовать `detail=False`:

```
@action(methods=['POST'], detail=False)
def register(self, request):
    serialized = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serialized.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=serialized.data['username'],
            password=serialized.data['password'],
            email=serialized.data['email']
        )
        user.save()
        return Response('user registered', status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response('invalid data', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Подскажите ещё, пожалуйста, можно ли каким-то образом создавать @action с одинаковым названием, для использования как с объектом, так и с коллекцией?

Comment: При объявлении двух методов с одинаковым именем внутри тела класса будет использоваться нижний по коду. Ну и `detail` является обязательным аргументом для декоратора  `action`, придётся использовать либо `True` либо `False`.